# CSS: How can handle height of 2 <div> be same with other when they are side by side, in situation that content of page will change after load page

Tags: css

Please be patient. There are many question like my question, but my question is different of them.

Style of my page divides page to 'left' and 'right' panel like this:

[image]

I implemented this style with `div` and `CSS`(using from float property).

This is necessary You know, in page user can adding content (table rows of data ). Also height and position of "Logo" and "Page Footer" is fix.
Therefore when user add new data, only height of "navigation menu" can be changed.

My problem is when height of page content (left panel) was increased, height of right panel doesn't change. Therefore some area of page was left blank.

My goal is when height of left panel was increased, right panel will stretch automatically by change height of "navigation menu" `div`.

You can see simplified of my code in below, And in this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M_i_T/2Lhtpq58/) and test it.

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='right'>
    <div id='logo'>Site Name</div>
    <div id='menus'>
        Nav Menus
    </div>
    <div id='copyright'>CopyRight</div>
</div>

<div id='left'>
    <div id='content'>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
    </div>

    <div id='button-wrapper'><button type='button' text='Add' onclick='add();'>add</button></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {float: right; height:100%;}
#right {float: right; width: 3cm;}

#left {float: right; width: 7cm; min-height: 6.1cm; height: 100%;}
#menus { min-height: 4cm; height: 100%; }
#logo, #copyright {height: 1cm;}

#logo, #menus, #copyright, #content, #left, #wrapper {border: 1px solid black;}
div{padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
```

JavaScript:

```
function add(){$("#content").append('<p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>');}
```

You must know any of panel have its border and its background color, therefore I can't use this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/). Because page will be disrupted.

At the end, I know can solve this problem by using `JavaScript`. But I search `CSS` solution.
Have anybody `CSS` solution?

Comment: Does it have to work in older Internet Explorer versions? (IE7, IE8, IE9)

Comment: Dear [@chrona](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2219120/chrona), I don't know, perhaps it work in them. Range of users is very various.

Comment: Flexbox can do that but without knowing the minimum browser level of support it's hard to offer a single solution other than Javascript. Oh...and `cm`...that's an odd value to use in web dev.

Comment: Dear [@Paulie_D](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d), I know using 'cm' is unusual way in web develop. But, because in my project, every thing must have exactly same layout in any platform. And we don't want dependent on screen resolution, screen size, browser Interpretation of code and so on... , we decided develop everything in hard way, but with clear scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@chrona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2219120/chrona)'s solution has educational tips for me, therefore I voted up it. but when I apply it on my project, problem wasn't solved. also some section of his code is obscure, and i don't understand logic of it.

So, I wrote new code by inspiration of [@chrona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2219120/chrona)'s solution.

You can see complete code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M_i_T/84rLrhe4/) and test it.

In new code, I used of `display: table` and its paraphernalia instead of `float` and `position`

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<!--- ---------- Left Panel ---------- --->
<div id='left'>
    <div id='content'>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
        <p>Some text Or Some table Row</p>
    </div>
    <div id='button-wrapper'>
        <button type='button' text='Add' onclick='add();'>add</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!--- -------------------------------- --->
<!--- ---------- Right Panel ---------- --->
<div id='right'>
    <div id='right_wrapper'>
        <div id='logo'>Site Name</div>
        <div id='menus'>
            <div id='menus_wrapper'>
            Nav Menus
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='copyright'>CopyRight</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--- -------------------------------- --->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* *{padding: 0; margin: 0} */
#wrapper
    {min-height: 7cm;}
#right, #left, #logo, #menus, #copyright
    {border: 1px solid black;}
#right
    {display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 3cm;
    background-color: #B5E51D;
    height: 100%;}

#left
    {display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 7cm;
    min-height: 100cm;
    height: 100%;}

#right_wrapper
    {display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;}

#logo, #copyright
    {display: table-row; width: 100%; height: 0.75cm;}
#menus
    {display: table-row; width: 100%; min-height: 5cm;}
#menus_wrapper
    {display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 4.25cm;}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achive this, depending what you want. As your .logo and .copyright seem to have fixed height a simple solution would be to use `position: absolute` and a calculated height:

http://jsfiddle.net/bsc8dkkL/2/

```
.wrapper, .logo, .menu, .copyright {
    border: 1px solid #444;
}

.wrapper {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.content { float: left; min-height: 150px; }
.sidebar { float: right; }

.logo, .menu, .copyright {
    width: 200px;
}

.logo, .copyright {
    height: 20px;
}

.menu, .copyright { position: absolute; }
.menu { bottom: 20px; top: 20px; }
.copyright { bottom: 0; }
```

The menu is given a calculated height which is always underneath the logo and on top of the footer.

Other ways to achieve this are by using the css-property `display: table` (IE8 and upwards), or `display: flex` with fallbacks (IE9+).

Flexbox is actually the easier solution, but isn't available in every browser.